# What is the name of this relationship between objects?

Tags: uml, diagrams, dependencies, relationships

Different types of dependencies have particular names, such as *linear dependency*, *circular dependency*, *self-referencing object*, etc.

What is the name of the dependency where those rules are true?

1. A has zero or more B,
2. B has zero or more C, and:
3. A has zero or more C.

   [image: An UML diagram illustrating the relationship described above]

If there is no particular name for such relationship, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What did you use to draw that diagram ? I like the colors :) .

Comment: @RaduMurzea: Visual Studio 2010. In Ultimate version, it has the features related to UML diagrams. The colors are the default colors Visual Studio uses.

Comment: is `one to many` no good?

Comment: @Brad: *one to many* is each of three relations. I'm looking for a name which designates all three relations together given their specificity (i.e. that C is linked to A not only through B, but also directly).

Comment: Why are you looking for a name?

Comment: @vainolo: because I'm working on a project which deals with different dependencies, so naming them correctly in code, documentation and tests is important for further understanding. Actually, I named it "pass-through dependency", but I would prefer either a well-known/official term already used to designate this sort of dependency, or at least something less  
inaccurate.

Comment: Are the C objects that B can have the same C objects that A has?

Comment: @RandallCook: Given that C has inevitably a link to A and to B, ∀c, c∈Bₓ, Aₓ∈Bₓ: c∈Aₓ: we assume, for the sake of simplicity, that consistency would require *c* to be linked to the same Aₓ as the related Bₓ. But ∀c, c∈Aₓ, Aₓ∈Bₓ doesn't imply that c∈Bₓ (since *c* can be linked to a different Bₓ).

Comment: sounds somewhat graph-like to me .. with additional union rules as delineated to @RandallCook by the OP

Comment: Transitive dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there were no answers for a while, I suppose that there is no well-known, widely used name for this relationship. Therefore, my own suggestion is to use:

- *pass-through dependency* : the dependency where C is linked to A at the same time directly and through B,
- *pass-through inconsistent dependency* : the specific case where C<sub>1</sub> is linked to A<sub>1</sub>, while being linked to B<sub>1</sub> which in turn is linked to C<sub>2</sub>.
- *multi-path dependency* : another possible term, which may be more explicit when the dependency is more complex; for example, C may be linked to A directly (C → A), through B (C → B → A), and through D+E (C → D → E → A).

  [image]